# Grid continuation

Tags: php, html, css, twig

I'm trying to make it so that when the grid is empty, then that it was filled with empty squares.
And when we add something to the grid, then the empty squares should decrease in the same order, and not vice versa.

```
<span class="box">
      {% for item in box %}
         <samp>
            <img src="{{ path(item.item_id) }}">
         </samp>
      {% endfor %}
      
      {% for i in 0..23-box | length %}
          <samp></samp>
      {% endfor %}
</span>
```

And it turns out that there are no last squares, but it is necessary that they always fill the entire line.

```css
.box{display:flex;align-content:flex-start;flex-wrap:wrap;overflow:hidden auto;width:260px;height:152px;margin:0 auto;}
.box samp{width:32px;height:32px;border:1px solid #393839;margin:3px 3px 1px 3px;padding:0;position:relative;}
```

```html
<span class="box">
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>

          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
    </span>
```

That is, it should be like this:

```css
.box{display:flex;align-content:flex-start;flex-wrap:wrap;overflow:hidden auto;width:260px;height:152px;margin:0 auto;}
.box samp{width:32px;height:32px;border:1px solid #393839;margin:3px 3px 1px 3px;padding:0;position:relative;}
```

```html
<span class="box">
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>
             <samp>
                1
             </samp>

          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          <samp>1</samp>
          
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
          <samp></samp>
    </span>
```

Connoisseurs, help me out, I've been suffering for 2 days ...
I just can't figure out how to make everything automatically adjust...
Initial grid dimensions:
6 pieces wide, 23 pieces high.
And then, it should dynamically build itself depending on the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill up the entire grid you'll need `6 * 23 = 138` boxes
You can either change your second loop or use `batch`

```
<span class="box">
      {% for item in box %}
         <samp>
            <img src="{{ path(item.item_id) }}">
         </samp>
      {% endfor %}
      
      {% for i in 0..138-box | length - 1 %}
          <samp></samp>
      {% endfor %}
</span>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/j1gidk)

---

The filter [`batch`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/batch.html) takes a second argument which will fill up the remaining items when the `box|length` < 138
Meaning `items` will always contain 138 items

```
<span class="box">
      {% for items in box|batch(138, '') %}
          {% for item in items %}
             <samp>
                {% if item.item_id|default %} {# test if item is empty or not #}
                    {{ item.item_id }}
                {% endif %}
             </samp>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
</span>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/2fbvwc)

---

Edit: It seems you only want to fill the rows, not the height. Then you definitely should use `batch`

```
<span class="box">
      {% for row in box|batch(6, '') %}
          {% for item in row %}
             <samp>
                {% if item.item_id|default %}
                    {{ item.item_id }}
                {% endif %}
             </samp>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
</span>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/tlmq1w)

Comment: Doesn't work. not properly. When there are items in the grid, and if their number is not yet 23 since the position starts from 0, the grid should not increase. When it became 24, the grid should increase, by the amount that is not enough to the end, that is, 5.

Comment: So you only want to fill up the current line and not the height correct?

Comment: Squares should be added only when the required number of squares is not enough on the new line, that is, only 6 of them fit in one line. that is, if 1 appears there, then 5 will be missing. And only 23 squares by default, even if there is not a single item...

Comment: Edited so only the last row gets filled up completely

Comment: Now it's working great! From the heart!